# Imagem exibida em uma máquina, e em outra não no Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho um app em django que roda em dois lugares, um no trabalho, que é onde há produção efetiva, e em minha casa, que é onde faço os ajustes pois aqui tenho tempo. O projeto esta hospedado no bitbucket e sempre uso a mesma versão do projeto, tanto no trabalho como em casa. O projeto roda perfeito nos dois ambientes, com uma exceção... A versão que roda em minha casa não está exibindo uma imagem que está no `/static/img/`, na máquina do meu trabalho está exibindo normal (lá roda em um servidor debian, com mod wsgi), e aqui em casa roda no servidor do python mesmo no linux deepin 15.5.

Está o {% load static %} no topo das páginas que está sendo exibida a imagem, e o caminho da imagem está assim:

```
<img src="{% static 'img/brasao.jpg' %}" widt="100" height="100"/><br>
```

Alguma ideia do motivo de isso estar acontecendo?

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url    

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^serf/', admin.site.urls),
#url(r'', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^jet/', include('jet.urls', 'jet')),  # Django JET URLS
    url(r'^i/', include('cadastro.urls')),
```

**urls.py** (de dentro da pasta do app)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import EmissaoTituloDetail
from .views import LaudoImovelDetail
from .views import ImovelDetail
from .views import NotificacaoDetail

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^titulos/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', EmissaoTituloDetail.as_view(), 
name='emissao_titulo_detail'),
    url(r'^laudo/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', LaudoImovelDetail.as_view(), 
name='laudo_imovel_detail'),
    url(r'^encaminhamento/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ImovelDetail.as_view(), 
name='encaminhamento_detail'),
    url(r'^notificacao/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', NotificacaoDetail.as_view(), 
name='notificacao_detail'),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Em modo de desenvolvimento/produção, o Django realmente não vai servir os arquivos estáticos (já que ele espera que essa responsabilidade seja passada pra um apache/nginx). Mas por questōes de facilidade, ele ainda permite que você faça isso se necessário.

Lá no seu `urls.py` você só precisa fazer isso:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Link da documentação: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, nao funcionou aqui, quando coloco pra copiar o end da imagem aparentemente ele da o caminho correto (http://localhost:8000/static/img/brasao.jpg) , e a imagem esta em /static/img/, porem nao esta sendo exibida a imagem em si

Comment: No terminal aparece algum 404 para essa imagem?

Comment: sim sim, da 404 no terminal, mas a imagem esta na pasta correta

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e coloca também o seu `urls.py` e a parte do `settings.py` que tem sobre os arquivos estáticos?

Comment: adicionei la amigo. tem dois arquivos urls.py, um geral,e  um dentro da pasta do app, por via das duvidas coloquei os dois, eles estao como antes de eu ter feito a alteração que vc sugeriu, mas coloquei em ambos o que vc disse e nao funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se foi um simples erro de digitação quando inseriu seu código na pergunta, mas está faltando um "h" na tag da imagem:

```
<img src="{% static 'img/brasao.jpg' %}" widt="100" height="100"/><br>
```

o correto seria:

```
<img src="{% static 'img/brasao.jpg' %}" width="100" height="100"/><br>
```